# jQGrid - Change Order of Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid which is loading data via AJAX and getting an JSON response.

I would like to know if there is a way to change the order of columns in the colModel of the grid without affecting the mapping of the cell data?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method in jqGrid API called [remapColumns](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods):

```
$("#list").remapColumns([0,2,1,3,4],true,false);
```

There was an error in some older versions of jqGrid -> indexes in the permutation array were 1-based, not 0-based. You should also remember that all additional/hidden columns (rownumber, multiselect, etc.) are counted as well.