# Ordering the columns on particular attribute while creating the grid using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in my project . Server is sending me the column attributes like

```
headerName:{
  'NAME':{caption:'Name',visible:true,order:2},
  'ADDRESS':{caption:'Address',visible:true,order:1}  
}
```

Order specifies the order in which columns dispaly like Address is first and Name is second.
Is it possible to use order in colModel and order the column according to the user while creating the grid ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666763/jqgrid-change-order-of-columns and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062052/jqgrid-columns-reorder

Comment: @shv22 Thanks i tried that one before but the problem was my server is sending me order not in the sequence like 1,2,3,4,5 there are some numbers missing like 2 is missing it just looks like 1,3,4,5,6 . So i sorted the json response accordingly and the issue is resolved.